# Randomize Image and Color Pair on Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, random, colors

I'm looking to randomize a image and color pair on my webpage upon refresh. For example, when you refresh, it will show "img A" and "#999;", and next it might show "img B" and "#fff;"; basically, one image is paired with exactly one color, and that color never goes with a different image.

The tricky part is that I need the color to randomize under the css/div "a:hover{", and the image to randomize under a different id (i named it #scanner, if it helps)

So far I have this, but it isn't working. I'm not very experienced with javascript so I'm totally stuck (even though i probably just missed something very simple).

```
<script>

 var colors = [["#CCCCCC",     "http://static.tumblr.com/ixbct68/1y1niuvxl/wwo.gif"], ["#7b9fb9",     "http://static.tumblr.com/ixbct68/2bzniuwcf/nottarget.gif"], ["#3df756",     "http://static.tumblr.com/ixbct68/eFxniuwqz/nonlethal.gif"]];

  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  document.getElementById("scanner").innerHTML = "<font   color=\"" +     pairs[r][0] + "\"<img src=\"" + pairs[r][1] +   "\">"

  text.css('color', colors[col][0]);
  </script>



<div id="scanner">
<script>
    document.getElementById("scanner").innerHTML = "<img src = \"" +     colors[col][1] + "\">"
  </script>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have three items in the array, but you are creating a random number between 0 and 3 (four different values), so sometimes it will try to get items outside the array. Create a random number between 0 and 2, or better yet just use the length of the array, so that it automatically adjusts to whatever you put in the array:

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
```

After that you try to access an element that doesn't exist yet. As the element is further down in the page, the code for it hasn't been parsed yet when the script runs. You should put the code after the element, or in the `load` event of the page.

The code uses an array named `pairs` that doesn't exist, and the HTML code that it produces is wrong. There is a `font` element (which is deprecated by the way) that doesn't have a closing bracket (`>`) and no closing tag (`</font>`). Something like this is what you would use:

```
document.getElementById("scanner").innerHTML = '<span style="color:' + colors[r][0] + '"><img src="' + colors[r][1] + '"></span>';
```

Then there is some code that uses a variable `text` that doesn't exist.

Then you have the element that you want to change, and more script inside that element. Changing the element while it is still being parsed (i.e. before the closing tag) might have some unexepected or unpredictable behaviour, for example that the closing tag might produce another element, or work as a closing element for some other element.

The script in the element repeats some of the earlier script, but it doesn't use the color.

Let's put the code in correct order, and clean out what you don't need:

```html
<div id="scanner"></div>

<script>

  var colors = [
    ["#CCCCCC", "http://static.tumblr.com/ixbct68/1y1niuvxl/wwo.gif"],
    ["#7b9fb9", "http://static.tumblr.com/ixbct68/2bzniuwcf/nottarget.gif"],
    ["#3df756", "http://static.tumblr.com/ixbct68/eFxniuwqz/nonlethal.gif"]
  ];

  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  document.getElementById("scanner").innerHTML = '<span style="color:' + colors[r][0] + '"><img src="' + colors[r][1] + '"></span>';

</script>
```

Comment: I see what I did wrong now; It works perfectly! I apologize for taking up your time. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Vio: Np. What would this site be without people doing something wrong... :)